# WPF - Capture an event from a control that is not on top

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that I am working on where there is a button that is obscured by a partially opaque rectangle overlay. The button is still visible, but it can not receive any events because they are all caught by the rectangle which is on top of it.

Is there any way to set a pass-through so that the event is received by the next visual item underneath?  If not is there some other workaround that could be used in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Set IsHitTestVisible="false" on the opaque overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set IsHitTestVisible="False" for the control over your button.

This example shows that a button is covered by a border, but the border doesn't get any event since because of the IsHitTestVisible="False" condition of border:

```
<Grid Background="Yellow">
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="25"/>
    <Border Background="Cyan" Opacity="0.4" Width="200"  Height="200" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
</Grid>
```

C# code,

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("iiiiiii");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the your own event to the rectangle event (or in the click event of the rectangle it self) and check there if it's with in buttons area

```
Rectangle.Click += your_click_event;
private void your_click_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 //check if it's coordinates are within the underlining button.
 //fire button click event

}
```

But it would be more convient to set

```
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

Like mentioned in other posts. [UIElement.IsHitTestVisible Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to look in to routed events in WPF. Routed events get routed based primarily on the visual tree. Routed events support a RoutingStrategy of Bubble, Tunnel, or Direct.

[Understanding Routed Events and Commands In WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx)